# Should Bash exit 1 show anything on the terminal?

Tags: bash, shell

If another script or process, such as the sequential tasks in a Gitlab .gitlab-ci.yml file for instance, depend on a Bash script exiting without an error to continue, or fail to exit further execution; should the Bash script do any thing else than exit 0 for success or exit 1 for catch all errors?

Example code below tests if a site was successfully deployed.

```
#!/bin/bash

flag="false"
for i in {1..10}
    do
        response=$(curl -Is http://mysite/ | head -n 1 |  tr -d '\r')
        echo "$response"
        if [ "$response" = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]; then
            echo "SITE UP"
            flag="true"
            exit 0
        fi
        sleep 1s
done
if [ "$flag" = "false" ]; then
    echo "SITE DOWN"
    exit 1
fi
```

Everything works 100% as expected, and the script is executed as `./test-up.sh > /dev/null` to suppress the debugging echos used (as well as text returned by the curl command).

However, if the script fails nothing is printed on the command line with regard to errors. The command line stays blank. The same happens if exit 0 was encountered.

Is the above intended?

Comment: If you're redirecting standard output to `/dev/null`, then, yes, not printing out anything is normal since none of the echos in that script print to standard error.

Comment: @Shawn Shouldn't `2>/dev/null` be used to suppress errors?

Comment: That would redirect standard error to `/dev/null`, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Echo to stderr

```
echo "SITE DOWN" >&2
```